# How to create an ImageButton in java and pass in a picture for it

Tags: java, android, imagebutton

I am trying to create an ImageButton in the java based off of user interaction, but when I pass in null it quits the application.

```
    ImageButton ib = new ImageButton(null);
```

How can I create an ImageButton in the java. I know how to do it in xml, but want to add x amount of buttons.

Comment: I think you are supposed to pass context.

Comment: What for context though? Just the words context?

Comment: it is called with this method getApplicationContext(), look at the answer by Salauyou.